# Table name type

Tags: postgresql

I have Postgresql DB with separate table for each worker,the table name as the worker name.
I have a table that holds workerID and workerName.
I want to make a function the will insert the data to the correct table by ID.
part of the code:

```
DECLARE 
  user_name text ;
BEGIN
  user_name := (select user FROM workerTable WHERE workerID = TG_ARGV[2])::text;
  INSERT INTO user_name::tablename ...
```

I'll be happy for any guidelines in this subject. 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

My guideline is you shouldn't be using a separate table for each worker.